# How to pass javascript prompt value to a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

Is there a way to pass a js popup value directly to a python/django view, or is necessary to capture this value with a javascript function and then do an ajax call?

For example:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {

$('#submit').click(function() { 
    var name=prompt("Please enter your name","");
  });
}
</script>
```

If it can be done directly, how would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do something along the lines of:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var name = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
    $.post('/url/to/django/handler', {'name': name});
});
```

to get the value the user filled out in the prompt back to your django app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the current view, you can use Javascript to modify the DOM, as in:

```
$('#myDiv').html(name)
```

Which will replace the contents of the div with id "myDiv" with the value you captured in "name".

If you're talking about a different view entirely, then you're always going to have to do a server call (via AJAX or a form submission) to get the value from the client to the server!